# How to show a region defined by an inequality within the specified domain?

Tags: plotting, graphics, regions, inequalities

Firstly, I wrote the following code to specifiy the domain of the variables `a` and `x`:

```
equ = -504 a (-1 + x)^9 - (
   2 (4 (-1 + x)^3 x + a (3 + x (-13 - 4 (-3 + x) x)))^4)/(-1 + 
     x)^3 + 2 x (2 (-1 + x)^3 (-1 + 2 x) + 
      a (3 + x (-13 - 4 (-3 + x) x)))^3 - 
   4 (4 + 193 a) (-1 + x)^6 (-4 (-1 + x)^3 x + 
      a (-3 + x (13 + 4 (-3 + x) x))) - 
   24 (1 + 16 a) (-1 + x)^3 (-4 (-1 + x)^3 x + 
      a (-3 + x (13 + 4 (-3 + x) x)))^2 - 
   4 (3 + 16 a) (-4 (-1 + x)^3 x + a (-3 + x (13 + 4 (-3 + x) x)))^3;

Plot[{2 x + x^2 /. 
   NSolve[{equ == 0, 0 < x < 1/2, 
     2 (-1 + x)^3 < 
      4 x^4 + 3 a + 12 x^2 (1 + a) - 4 x^3 (3 + a) - x (4 + 13 a) < 
      0}, x], x /. 
   NSolve[{equ == 0, 0 < x < 1/2, 
     2 (-1 + x)^3 < 
      4 x^4 + 3 a + 12 x^2 (1 + a) - 4 x^3 (3 + a) - x (4 + 13 a) < 
      0}, x]}, {a, 0, 1.5}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {a, f},
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, PlotRange -> All, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

The output is the following:
[image]

As shown in the graph, the domain of the variables `a` and `x` is the shaded area. It is the region between two curves defined by `2 x + x^2` and `x` with `0 <= a <= 1.5`, where `x` is an implicit function of `a` such that `equ == 0`.

Now my question is that: how to plot the sub-region defined by the following inequality within the specified domain shown in the above graph?

```
1/(x + 1) + Log[x + 1]/(x + 1)^3 + x^2 > 0.8 a*x + 1/(a^5*x^2 + 1)
```

I'm thinking about using code `RegionPlot` to plot it. However, it seems that `RegionPlot` can only show the region within a rectangle (something like `a1 < a < a2` and `x1 < x < x2`). But in this problem, the domain is not a rectangle. So how can I solve this problem?

BTW, as a try to find the answer, I used `RegionPlot` to show the region defined by the inequality within a rectangle with `0 < a < 1.5` and `0 < x < 1`. Then I used `Show` to combine the two graphs to obtain the common area of the two graphs, which should be the answer to this question. The code is as follows:

```
RegionPlot[
  1/(x + 1) + Log[x + 1]/(x + 1)^3 + x^2 > 
   0.8 a*x + 1/(a^5*x^2 + 1), {a, 0, 1.5}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.6}, {0, 1}}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Classic"];

Show[%3214, %3211]
```

The output is the following:
[image]

As displayed in the above graph, the common area (shown in purple color) is the answer to this question. However, it is NOT perfect, because I want to show the region defined by the inequality within the specified domain (so the blue area is redundant and should be removed). Is there some way to solve this problem perfectly?

Comment: Please fix the code `Show[%3172, %3211]`.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the post.

Comment: …Please remove those `%` from the code so we can easily test it.

Answer (score 3):

Though we can plot such intersection, but I still agree with @xzczd and @Bob Hanlon that we have change the original implicit function since`{a,x}->{a,2 x + x^2}`

```
equ = -504 a (-1 + 
      x)^9 - (2 (4 (-1 + x)^3 x + 
        a (3 + x (-13 - 4 (-3 + x) x)))^4)/(-1 + x)^3 + 
  2 x (2 (-1 + x)^3 (-1 + 2 x) + a (3 + x (-13 - 4 (-3 + x) x)))^3 - 
  4 (4 + 193 a) (-1 + x)^6 (-4 (-1 + x)^3 x + 
     a (-3 + x (13 + 4 (-3 + x) x))) - 
  24 (1 + 16 a) (-1 + x)^3 (-4 (-1 + x)^3 x + 
      a (-3 + x (13 + 4 (-3 + x) x)))^2 - 
  4 (3 + 16 a) (-4 (-1 + x)^3 x + 
      a (-3 + x (13 + 4 (-3 + x) x)))^3; 

domain = 
 ContourPlot[equ == 0, {a, 0, 1.6}, {x, 0, 1/2}, PlotPoints -> 80, 
  MaxRecursion -> 4, PlotRange -> All];
pts = Cases[domain // Normal, Line[pt_] :> pt, -1];
tranpts = pts /. {a_Real, x_Real} :> {a, 2 x + x^2};
reg1 = Polygon[Join[pts[[1]], Reverse@tranpts[[1]]]];
reg2 = ImplicitRegion[
    1/(x + 1) + Log[x + 1]/(x + 1)^3 + x^2 > 
     0.8 a*x + 1/(a^5*x^2 + 1), {{a, 0, 1.5}, {x, 0, 1}}] // 
   BoundaryDiscretizeRegion;
intersection = RegionIntersection[reg1, reg2];
Graphics[{{Opacity[.2], Green, reg1}, {Red, intersection}, {Thick, 
   ColorData[97][1], Line[pts], Line[tranpts]}}, Axes -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I have one question: can you remove the blue area in your graph? I don't want to show this area, because the question in my post is that "showing the sub-region defined by the inequality within the specified doman (i.e., the green area in your graph)". The blue area is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

equ = -504 a (-1 + 
       x)^9 - (2 (4 (-1 + x)^3 x + 
         a (3 + x (-13 - 4 (-3 + x) x)))^4)/(-1 + x)^3 + 
   2 x (2 (-1 + x)^3 (-1 + 2 x) + a (3 + x (-13 - 4 (-3 + x) x)))^3 - 
   4 (4 + 193 a) (-1 + x)^6 (-4 (-1 + x)^3 x + 
      a (-3 + x (13 + 4 (-3 + x) x))) - 
   24 (1 + 16 a) (-1 + x)^3 (-4 (-1 + x)^3 x + 
       a (-3 + x (13 + 4 (-3 + x) x)))^2 - 
   4 (3 + 16 a) (-4 (-1 + x)^3 x + a (-3 + x (13 + 4 (-3 + x) x)))^3;

xval = Assuming[{0 < x < 1/2, 0 < a < 3/2},
    Solve[{equ == 0, 0 < x < 1/2, 0 < a < 3/2}, x] // Simplify][[1]];

Show[
 Plot[{2 x + x^2 /. xval, x /. xval}, {a, 0, 3/2},
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {a, f}),
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue},
  PlotRange -> All,
  Filling -> {1 -> {2}},
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{2 x + x^2, x}, {.5, .2}],
  WorkingPrecision -> 15],
 RegionPlot[
  Evaluate[x <= y <= 2 x + x^2 &&
      1/(x + 1) + Log[x + 1]/(x + 1)^3 + x^2 > 
       4/5 a*x + 1/(a^5*x^2 + 1) /. xval] && 0 <= a <= 3/2,
  {a, 0, 3/2}, {y, 0, 4/5},
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.75, Yellow],
  BoundaryStyle -> {Gray, Thin},
  WorkingPrecision -> 15]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it seems not correct. Pls read my post (I just updated it).

Comment: When the plots are overlapped they must be drawn on the same axes. The vertical axes in your original plot is not `x`, it is `f` or `y` or whatever you want to call it other than `x`. In the subregion, `x` must be same as `x` in the larger region, i.e., defined by the solution to `equ == 0`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't think it's relevant to call `x` `f` or `y`. Pls notice that `x` is an implicit function of `a`. Indeed, `x` and `a` have to satisfy `equ (a, x) == 0`.

Comment: I checked a few times. I don't think your anwer is correct. The subregion defined by the inequality is not the yellow area in your graph.

Comment: By definition, `x` as a function of `a` is the lower boundary of the region -- not the axis.

Comment: Yes, `x` is the lower boundary of the specified domain. The sub-region defined by the inequality within the specified domain should be the area of purple color in the second graph in my post. But my code is not perfect, since there are "redundant regions" in that graph.

Comment: I repeat, **When the plots are overlapped they must be drawn on the same axes** I am leaving this discussion.

Comment: @YaHe Notice in the first `Plot[…]` you're plotting `x` **and `2 x + x^2`**. The vertical axis does not represent `x` at all.

Comment: @xzczd Yes, I got your point. I have updated the post and corrected the vertical axis label (I replaced `x` with `f` to aviod possible confusion).

Comment: @BobHanlon thanks for your comment. I have replaced `x` with `f` as the vertical axis label to avoid confusion.